# Cassandra TTL not working

Tags: cassandra, datastax, ttl

I am using datastax with cassandra. I want a row to be automatically deleted after 15 minutes of its insertion. But the row still remains.

My code is below:

```
Insert insertStatement = QueryBuilder.insertInto(keySpace, "device_activity");
        insertStatement.using(QueryBuilder.ttl(15* 60));
        insertStatement.value("device", UUID.fromString(persistData.getSourceId()));
        insertStatement.value("lastupdatedtime", persistData.getLastUpdatedTime());
        insertStatement.value("devicename", persistData.getDeviceName());
        insertStatement.value("datasourcename", persistData.getDatasourceName());
```

The table consist of 4 columns : device (uuid), datasourcename(text), devicename(text), lastupdatedtime (timestamp).

If I query the TTL of some field it shows me 4126 seconds which is wrong.
//Select TTL(devicename) from device_activity; // Gives me 4126 seconds

Comment: The query finally being executed is                                                           INSERT INTO devicecloud_test.device_activity(device,lastupdatedtime,devicename,datasourcename) VALUES (ca5cff1f-b23a-426a-ba3f-f13300a2d8e6,1461150305100,'TestBench162','259642460471175') USING TTL 60;

Comment: I don't understand, the TTL which is used by Cassandra, is it 4126 or 60 seconds ?

Comment: I have given 900 seconds, but cassandra is showing me 4126 seconds

Comment: QueryBuilder.ttl(15* 60) // In this line, i am giving 900 seconds.

Comment: Just print the `insertStatement.getQueryString()` before executing it to see which TTL is really assigned

Comment: I could resolve the issue. One of the node of cassandra was not in time sync. When ever the data was inserted in that node the TTL query from my machine it was giving wrong value.  I fixed it by resetting the corresponding machine to proper time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below link, the explanation of TTL is provided.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_expire_c.html

"TTL data has a precision of one second, as calculated on the server. Therefore, a very small TTL probably does not make much sense. Moreover, the clocks on the servers should be synchronized; otherwise reduced precision could be observed because the expiration time is computed on the primary host that receives the initial insertion but is then interpreted by other hosts on the cluster."

After reading this i could resolve by setting proper time on the corresponding node(machine.)